# Android To Make A Running Distance Calculation app

Tags: android, gps

I am started learning android a few days ago and I wanted to design an app where I can calculate the distance, time and speed I have run by using gps.

So I have tried couple of examples and gone through some of the tutorials. I have written the following code.

But the is just giving me the gps locations but it is not calculating the distance and speed can any one tell me where is my problem and how to solve it.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class test extends Activity implements Runnable {
     private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
        private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 3;

        protected LocationManager locationManager;
        Location location;
        static double n=0;
        Long s1,r1;
        double plat,plon,clat,clon,dis;
        MyCount counter;
        Thread t1;
        EditText e1;
        boolean bool=true;

    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//<--- current position
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);//<---- start moving.. calculates distance on clicking this
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);//<--- pause
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);//<-- resume
        b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);// <-- get distance
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
    });     

    }
    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            clat=location.getLatitude();
            clon=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(test.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "null location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    public void start (View v){

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button2:
            t1=new Thread();
            t1.start();
            counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
         counter.start();
         break;
        case R.id.button3:
            counter.cancel();
            bool=false;
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
         counter.start();
         bool=true;
         break;
        case R.id.button5:

            double time=n*30+r1;
            Toast.makeText(test.this,"distance in metres:"+String.valueOf(dis)+"Velocity in m/sec :"+String.valueOf(dis/time)+"Time :"+String.valueOf(time),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }


    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );

            Toast.makeText(test.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
         counter.start();
         n=n+1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            s1=millisUntilFinished;
            r1=(30000-s1)/1000;
            e1.setText(String.valueOf(r1));


        }
        }

    public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
        double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
        double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
        double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                        (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
        double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
        double dist = ang *6371;
        return dist;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (bool){

            clat=location.getLatitude();
            clon=location.getLongitude();
            if(clat!=plat || clon!=plon){
                dis+=getDistance(plat,plon,clat,clon);
                plat=clat;
                plon=clon;

            }

        }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are not using the distanceBetween or distanceTo methods and opted to calculate the distance your own way.  Does your formula calculate great circle distances?  It looks simpler than it ought to be.  Suggest you check this out.